# can the free threads be used in doing the work of other thread simultaneously in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 10 threads filling unique codes in 10 tables simultaneously. Each thread filling up million records. After sometimes 7 tables got filled up but the rest 3 are still filling up. I want to indulge the free 7 threads in filling up the tables simultaneously with the running 3 threads can this be done??

```
String noOfCodes = ""+((Integer.parseInt(totalOfCodes))/10);
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    String threadNo = ""+i;
    Runnable worker = new CodeGeneratorDAO(pgmId, digits, points, validity, noOfCodes, product, threadNo);
    executor.execute(worker);
    resp.setSuccess(true);
}

executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
}

System.out.println("Finished all threads");
```

Comment: Not with your current setup. Look into `ForkJoinPool` and divide and conquer paradigms. Currently you are hardcoding the split of work into `10` threads with `10` runnables.

Comment: And **NEVER EVER BUSY WAIT**. This code `while (!executor.isTerminated())` wastes one entire CPU! There is a reason that the `awaitTermination` method exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to define a `Runnable` executing a smaller task that your current `Runnable`. Breaking down the tasks will smooth the overall execution time.

You say that your Runnable "fills up 1000 records", so define your Runnable as filling up 1 record and submit all your 10 * 1000 records to be updated to your `ExecutorService`:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
for(Runnable oneRecordRunnable : allRunnables) {
    executor.submit(oneRecordRunnable);
}
executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

As a side note, I replaced your cpu-burning `while(true)` loop by the `awaitTermination` method.